# Will wolves eat ocelots in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't think my wolves would eat an ocelot but I've had one before and it disappeared. There was nowhere for it to leave my house and it was tame.

Comment: You mean attack?

Answer (score 6):

There is no mob-eat-mob action in Minecraft, besides wolves and sheep/ocelots and chickens. Tamed ocelots may disappear if they catch fire and die though. Do you have any fire in your house? It may have also got up of its own accord and wandered off. Cats will do this if you are harmed near them.

Comment: Don't you mean wolves and sheep?

Comment: @Arperum I do indeed

Answer (score 1):

If your ocelot is tamed, it won't despawn. It's possible that you may have accidently punched your ocelot, making the wolf aggressive towards it.

Answer (score 0):

The is no possible way that your ocelot got eaten by a wolf. I mean. Wolves kill sheep and ocelots kill chicken, but not ocelots. Maybe you accidently hitted it and it got away or it despawned (bug). But no, wolves don't eat ocelots.

Answer (score -1):

Fortunately wolves will not eat ocelots.  I think you ocelot may have despawned though.

Answer (score -1):

No wolves wont eat your ocelots